# Gimp always displays the wrong color for transparent layers

Tags: gimp

I have a problem (which I had previously on completely another Ubuntu and older versions of Gimp [now I have the latest - 2.8.10]). When I open PSDs with transparent layers, they get displayed in a wrong color and kind of shrinked.
I did set image mode to RGB. In Photoshop it displays properly with RGB color profile.

Here are the examples:

[photoshop page http://karunus.com/photoshop.png](http://karunus.com/photoshop.png)
[gimp page http://karunus.com/gimp.png](http://karunus.com/gimp.png)

What could be the issue?

Comment: What does "render the PSD" mean in this context? And is "they" the layers or the whole image? Maybe you can add examples/screenshots to improve your question.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher, I added photos. By 'render' I meant just 'open'.

Comment: The first is how it is supposed to look like, the second how it looks like in GIMP?

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher, yep, exactly (except for pics of course:-))

Comment: GIMP doesn't claim to support PSD fully, so this could be any number of reasons. However, those templates usually assume that you know a reasonable subset of Photoshop features inside out, so maybe you are just expected to show of hide some additional layers.

Note that GIMP does not support adjustment layers.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher, very much looks like the problem lies in adjustment layers actually. Any workaround around this?

Comment: No. Except for using Adobe Photoshop or any other application that claims to support those, of course. I never bothered to check which ones do, though.